# Newtons Method to solve equations

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

The question is the following:
 Use Newton’s method to solve 
$$x^3_1+x_2=1,\\
x^3_2−x_1=−1 $$
Indicate your initial condition and how many steps it requires to reach the tolerate of error to be within 10−6 .

I can generate the code for just one equation. I don't know how to do it for both equations. This is my code for one of them

```
 % Change here for different functions 
 f=@(x) x^(3)+x-1
 %this is the derivative of the above function
 df=@(x) 3*x^(2)+1
 % Change lower limit 'a' and upper limit 'b'
 a=0; b=1;
 x=a;
 for i=1:1:100
     x1=x-(f(x)/df(x));
     x=x1;
 end
 sol=x;
 fprintf('Approximate Root is %.15f',sol)
 a=0;b=1;
 x=a;
 er(5)=0;
 for i=1:1:5
     x1=x-(f(x)/df(x));
     x=x1;
     er(i)=x1-sol;
 end 
 plot(er) 
 xlabel('Number of iterations')
 ylabel('Error') 
 title('Error Vs. Number of iterations')
```

Comment: Please take 10 minutes to review formatting on this site.

Comment: One approach is to use substitution to get a single equation (sixth degree) in one unknown and solve that.  It is takes some thought to assess the error on the other variable but maybe you know something about error propagation.  This site is not about code review.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is

$$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1^3+x_2 \\ -x_1 + x_2^3 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Compute its Jacobian. Solve

$$\mathbf{x}_{n+1} = \mathbf{x}_n - \mathbf{J}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}_{n})\mathbf{x}_n.$$

You can write the function in MATLAB syntax as

```
f = @(x)[x(1)^3+x(2); -x(1)+x(2)^3];
```

The Jacobian I will leave to you.

Comment: Thank you! that step was my bigger confusion thanks a lot